# Explanation to the unexpected output

Tags: java

I wrote a simple program to test static functionality, when suddenly I can to this program of which I cannot determine the logic.

The code is in java, is as follows:

```
 class Demo{
    public static int Main(String[] ab){
        System.out.println("Hello Main");
        return 0;
    }
}
public class New{
    public static void main(String[] ab){
        String abc[]={"1","2"};
        System.out.println("Hello"+Demo.Main(abc));
    }
}
```

The Output this code gave is :

```
Hello Main
Hello0
```

According to my logic, this output must be

```
Hello Hello Main
0
```

Can Anyone explain the unexpected output of this program?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: "According to my logic, this output must be" - it's hard to explain why your logic is wrong when you don't *tell* us your logic. The program prints exactly what I'd expect it to, but without more information about why *you* expect the other output, it's hard to help. Hint: `Demo.Main(abc)` is evaluated completely (including printout) before `System.out.println()` is called within `main`. Try splitting it into multiple statements as an equivalent program...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `New.main` method executes this line

```
System.out.println("Hello" + Demo.Main(abc));
```

So before executing actually the `println` it must evaluate all the arguments. So it executes `Demo.Main` first. When it executes it it encounters

```
System.out.println("Hello Main");
return 0;
```

So it prints `Hello Main`, prints a new line and return 0. `Demo.Main(abc)` is evaluated now to 0 so it can continue the execution:

```
System.out.println("Hello" + 0);
```

And prints `Hello0`

Comment: Thank you, It helped me.

Answer (score 2):

The output is completely as expected.

Looks like the assumption you made is that you're `Demo.Main()` method would also *return* `Hello Main`, but it actually only writes that to standard output.

So the order of execution is:

1. `main()` is invoked
2. `Demo.Main()` is invoked
3. `Demo.Main()` writes `Hello Main` to standard output
4. `Demo.Main()` returns 0 to `main()`
5. `main()` writes "Hello" plus the 0 result to standard output

Comment: Thank you, It helped me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

So first the code inside your brackets is executed. This means `Demo.Main(abc)` will be run first and returns `0` after it finishes.

That means, you will see first a `Hello Main` on your console. After that on a newline it will print `Hello` and append the return value of `Demo.Main(abc)` (which is indeed `0`)

The resulted output is:

```
Hello Main
Hello0
```